# How to insert first element into list of lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists and want to insert a value into the first position of each list.  What is wrong with this code?  Why does it return none data types at first, and then if I access the variable again, it shows up with data? I end up with the right answer here, but I have a much larger list of lists I am trying to this with, and it does not work.  What is the right way to do this?  Thanks.

```
lol = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
[lol[i].insert(0,0) for i in np.arange(0,3)]
```

The results:

```
lol = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
[lol[i].insert(0,0) for i in np.arange(0,3)]
Out[201]: [None, None, None]

lol
Out[202]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Why do you want a list comprehension? Do you want new list objects or do you want to insert into the existing ones? What do you mean with "it does not work" when talking about the larger list? You also say you "end up with the right answer", so which is it? Do you get the right result or not? How large is your outer list and how large are your inner lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.insert` inserts the value *in-place* and always returns `None`. To add new value into a list with list comprehension you can do:

```py
lol = [[0, *subl] for subl in lol]
print(lol)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Even much more inefficient than the already inefficient `insert`, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy If you want to insert to a list at first position, it will be always inefficient (O(n))

Comment: That's why I said that that's already inefficient, yes. So is your point that they must not care about efficiency, as otherwise they wouldn't do this, so your worse inefficiency doesn't matter?

Comment: @KellyBundy The question is named "How to insert first element into list of lists using list comprehension" so I showed how it's done using list-comprehension.

Comment: They also ask "What is the right way to do this?", though, and I see no indication that they want new lists (they say "end up with the right answer") so I don't think this is the right way. Oh well, they already made up their mind...

Comment: @KellyBundy Please post a new answer here what you think is right way to do it. I'll upvote it :) It's always good to see alternatives.

Comment: Depends on their answers to my clarification questions, but they can't be bothered to answer those, abandoned their question instead :-(

Answer (score 3):

This will also do the trick.

```
lol = [[0] + l for l in lol]
```